# Visual Studio NuGet package manager not working with relative URI error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, uri, relative-path

I have a problem with Nuget Package Manager and Extension and updates manager on Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3.
This tools can list installed packages but cannot access to online packages.

The Nuget package manager write this error in the output : 
[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  Cette opération n'est pas prise en charge pour un URI relatif.  (This operation is not supported for a relative URI)

The Extensions and update manager displays the same error.

I have tried to repair Visual Studio, checked that there is no proxy on my OS nor http_proxy in environment variables, remove Visual Studio user settings.

Fiddler does not log any information.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any Nuget,config file?

Comment: Could you open the package source in the browser? Please check whether NuGet.config contain a package source with relative file path. The package source with relative file path is not supported. The NuGet.config files located in your solution folder or %AppData%\NuGet\nuget.config. Try to remove the relative file path and restart the VS, then access to online packages again.

Comment: The %AppData%\NuGet\nuget.config file is standard :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>`

The weird thing is that I have the same error in the classic Extension and Updates popup while browsing for online assemblies.

Comment: @Aurelien Dolande ,Which version of Nuget Package Manager you installed? and have you try to uninstall and reinstall the extension of NuGet package manager? If all those are not help you, please share the screenshot of the error in the classic Extension and Updates popup while browsing for online assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Found !

I have launched Visual Studio with the /log option.

The stacktrace in the log file was :

`Unexpected exception Cette op&#x00E9;ration n&apos;est pas prise en charge pour un URI relatif.

 System.Uri.get_Host()&#x000D;&#x000A;

 Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.VsWebProxy.&lt;PrepareWebProxyAsync&gt;d__6.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- Fin de la trace de la pile 
 partir de l&apos;emplacement pr&#x00E9;c&#x00E9;dent au niveau duquel l&apos;exception a &#x00E9;t&#x00E9; lev&#x00E9;e ---&#x000D;&#x000A;

 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;

 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;

 Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.VsWebProxyService.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass9_0.&lt;&lt;PrepareWebProxyAsync&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- Fin de la trace de la pile 
 partir de l&apos;emplacement pr&#x00E9;c&#x00E9;dent au niveau duquel l&apos;exception a &#x00E9;t&#x00E9; lev&#x00E9;e ---&#x000D;&#x000A;

 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;

 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;

 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;

 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()&#x000D;&#x000A;

 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserManager.&lt;ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy&gt;d__74.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- Fin de la trace de la pile`

By decompiling some VisualStudio dll, I have seen that it uses the WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy. On my computer, a third party application has modified my machine.config file : in configuration/system.net/defaultProxy, a module was specified.

After commenting this parts, it worked.

Thanks !

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.